# Mounting CD/DVD drive

Tags: mount, dvd

Trying to mount my cd/DVD drive so i can useit, currently when i put a disk in nothing happens. I'm trying to use wodim to detect the device and this is the output.

```
cmehmen@c:~$ wodim devices
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'ATAPI   '
Identification : 'DVD A  DH16A1L  '
Revision       : 'KH39'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE FORCESPEED 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
wodim: No such file or directory. Cannot open 'devices'.
```

I assume to access i must use the directory /dev/cdrom but im really new to this and am trying to learn. i have no experience at all with mounting and would appreciate the help please be thorough

Answer (score 1):

For detecting devices using wodim, the syntax is **wodim -devices**. You forgot the **-** before **devices**, so wodim thought you wanted to burn file **devices**.